# mongoDB java client : cursor iteration stop

Tags: java, mongodb

i have a collection of 1455413 documents (sentencesDB2.locations)
i need to process every document and create new document to a different db and collection (locationFeaturesAnalysisDB.features2).

For some reason, the process stops after 761447 documents, and when i tried to skip on these document it tells me that this document is already processed (the new document is already in the db). i tried to use all i know about query or cursor timeout

What im doing wrong? my code:

```
public static MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(Consts.serverAddress, new MongoClientOptions.Builder().maxWaitTime(Integer.MAX_VALUE).socketKeepAlive(true).build());
public static DBCollection sentencesCollection = mongo.getDB("sentencesDB2").getCollection("sentences");
public static DBCollection nounsCollection = mongo.getDB("sentencesDB2").getCollection("nouns");
public static DBCollection locationsCollection = mongo.getDB("sentencesDB2").getCollection("locations");
public static DBCollection dependenciesCollection = mongo.getDB("sentencesDB2").getCollection("dependencies");
public static DBCollection featuresCollection = mongo.getDB("locationFeaturesAnalysisDB").getCollection("features2");
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    long featuresSize = featuresCollection.count();
    DBCursor locations = locationsCollection.find().addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_NOTIMEOUT);
    System.out.println(locations.size());
    for(long i = 0;  locations.hasNext(); i ++)
    {
        DBObject location = locations.next();
        double distanceFromHotel = (Double) location.get("distanceFromHotel");
        Object nounId = location.get("nounId");
        System.out.println("treating noun :" + nounId);
        DBObject noun = nounsCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("_id", nounId)).next();
        Object sentenceId = noun.get("sentenceID");
        DBObject sentence = sentencesCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("_id", sentenceId)).next();

        DBCursor features = featuresCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("nounId", nounId)).addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_NOTIMEOUT);
        if(!features.hasNext())
        {
            int nounStartIndex = (Integer) noun.get("startIndex");
            int nounEndIndex = (Integer) noun.get("endIndex");
            BasicDBObject analysis = analyzeInstance(noun, sentence)
                    .append("nearby", (distanceFromHotel <= 2))
                    .append("nounId", nounId)
                    .append("sentenceId", sentenceId)
                    .append("locationId", location.get("_id"))
                    .append("sentence", sentence.get("sentence"))
                    .append("nounString", noun.get("nounString"))
                    .append("nounStartIndex", nounStartIndex)
                    .append("nounEndIndex", nounEndIndex)
                    .append("distanceFromHotel", distanceFromHotel);
            featuresCollection.insert(analysis);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("is in db");
        }
        features.close();

    }
    locations.close();
```

Thanks

Comment: You are saying that `noun` collection` is of 1400000 collections. but you are not iterating the `noun collection` but the `Location Collection`.  Also please add logs of the iteration process. show us the size is as you say and that the iteration stops when you say it stops.

Comment: i meant the location collection

Comment: the iteration is on the locations.. i tried to find the analyzed document in the features collection. there is no unique printout. the process exits normally, i saw in my robomongo this numbers

Comment: are u using sharded db?